# How django program flow from the js form to request object generation?

Tags: python, django, pagination

Ok, I have a web page in my django site. The page displays a table of data and the table can be sorted by it's columns. When I click on the header of one of those columns, the page
re-render itself with the url `www.oneOwesomeSite/theHolyPage?orderby=column6`
which is nice and dandy.

Now, when I click the bottom nav bar in order to paginate through table rows, the new url becomes something like
`www.oneOwesomeSite/theHolyPage?page=3` and the orderby filter is gone.

The question is who is creating the new request object, adding the page parameter to it while resting the orderby param.

Already know that when the program gets to run the the view.py file associated with this table, at this stage the request object is already set and the original params are lost.
Also located the HTML file from which pagination is called.

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $('.paginators').on("click", function(event){     
        $('#form-page').val($(this).data('page'));
        $('#search-form').submit();

    });
});
</script>
```

OK, got some progress here.

The HTML file has a form section:

```
<form id="search-form">
     <input type="hidden" id="form-page" name="page" value="{{ table.page.number }}">
     <input type="hidden" id="form-filter" name="filter_pk" value="{{ current_filter_pk }}">
     <!-- by default we sort the table by ascending names. User can change sort by another column by criteria by clicking it's header on the display  -->
     <input type="hidden" id="form-sort" name="sort" value="{{ table }}">
```

Now, if I change the pagination code here:

```
$('.paginators').on("click", function(event){     
        $('#form-page').val($(this).data('page'));
        $('#search-form').submit();

});
```

and add this line:

```
 $('#form-sort').val('date');
```

then the table gets to be sorted by the date column, in addition to pagination.
But this is hard coded. What do I have to put instead?

See the $('#form-page').val($(this).data('page')); line? 
'data-page' is related to the line:

and I assume data('page') gets it's content from {{ table.page.number }}.
Who is this table thing? Is it related to the django_tables2 API?
How can I query the properties of {{table}} and get the column property?

Man, it's not my code. And it's undocumented, naturally.

Comment: Its a bit confusing. What are you using any jquery table or django-tables2 or anything else ?

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier. It was weekend and I was out of the office.

I'm having crisp-forms. That may be related. Don't know about any other django api in my code that may tamper the request/response sequence. Also having django_tables2 in this app, whatever that is.

Darn it. Now I have figure out what those API actually do. Never wanted to know django anyway...